# Javascript - Conditionally selecting the condition of a while loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, conditional-statements

I need to fill an array with randomly selected elements until the array reaches an **appointed length**. The length of that array must be equal to the smallest of two lengths. We'll call them `length_1` and `length_2`. So if `length_1 < length_2`, then use `length_1`, otherwise, use `length_2`. Note that both lengths are constant so the statement `length_1 < length_2` will always give the same Boolean value.

The method I came up with to deal with that situation is to create a **while loop** which, at each turn, adds a new randomly selected element to the array. It goes like this:

```
while (
length_1 < length_2
  ? array.length < length_1
  : array.length < length_2
  ) {
    // Add a new randomly selected element to the array
     };
```

Is this a valid way to it? Is there a more concise way to go about it?

Comment: Since `length_1` and `length_2` don't change, you don't need to compare them at every loop. Just do it once before, take the smallest and use this value in your loop.

Comment: _"so the statement length_1 < length_2 will always give the same Boolean value"_ - Then why evaluate that _"same boolean value"_ on each round of the loop?

Comment: @DavePile [that's not true](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the minimum in advance for a looping condition.

```
const
    length = Math.min(length_1, length_2);

while (array.length < length) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's great, not sure why I hadn't thought of that before!

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid while loops. They are prone to get into an endless loop.

```
const length = Math.min(length_1, length_2);

for(let i = 0; i < length; i+=1) {
  //...
}
```